# How to get all user posts from two post types in wp_query

Tags: wp-query

When I add 'author' I only get results from "post" but no results are received from the "my_post_type_name"
My code:

```
$args = array(
    'author'        =>  $user_id,
    'post_type'      => array('my_post_type_name', 'post'),
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Is it possible? Or do I need two query?

Answer (score 0):

Ye. It is possible with single query.

WordPress is allowed to fetch posts from different post type. For example, consider the default post types "post" and "page"

To fetch user posts from "post" and "page", we can use the following query.

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'author' => $user_id,
    'post_type' => array('post', 'page'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1
        )
);
```

I have used `posts_per_page` as -1 to fetch all posts. This is working in a default WordPress install.

Refer [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-type-parameters) for more details.

Comment: Hey,
I changed the name so it would not be confused.
I did some tests and indeed when I enter "post" and "page" I get normal results but when I enter "my_post_type_name" I do not get its results. Only when he is alone without a "post" do I get his results

Answer (score 0):

problem solved!
The code works great,
The problem was that the "polylang" plugin filtered out undefined post typs.
When I turned off the plugin all the author's posts appeared